# How to create partially editable pdf (only 4 columns to 20) with itextsharp?

Tags: vb.net, itext, itext7

I need to create a pdf file similar to an excel table. Only 4 of the 20 columns must make them editable. How can I do ?
Thank you.

Comment: you tagged this question with vb.net, could you provide some code samples?

Comment: What have you tried yet? What is your blocker?